# How to detect if a connection request is from an existing connected client?

Tags: c#, tcpclient

In a TCP server, there is potential a remote client might decide the connection has failed (rightly or wrongly) and reconnect to my server. It is entirely possible my server thinks the original connection is still good so I want to check incoming connections to see if they match any existing connection.

I am not seeing an obvious way to compare `Socket` or `TcpClient` instances. Assuming I am not missing something obvious, what would be a normal way to do this? It must be a fairly common problem that servers need to handle.

e.g. pseudo:

```
TcpListener server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, port);

while(true)
{
 TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
 var oldClient = currentClients.FindMatching(client);
 //client must have re-connected for some reason, tidy up
 if(oldClient != null)
  currentClients.RemoveClient(oldClient);
 currentClients.AddClient(client);
}
```

*To meet the obvious comment, assume the communication protocol is from a 3rd party and is very basic: doesn't provide a client ID, or heartbeat/linkcheck. It just sends updates until it detects a problem then reconnects and starts again - so the TCP connection handler has to detect duplicate connections*

Comment: I'd make that part of the communication protocol. I'd have the client identify itself on connection (certificate, guid, ... whatever). Then you can lookup the id and see if there is an "old" dangling connection for the client. Or not even the client. Better a (virtual) connection id. Maybe at some point you need the client to have multiple connections simultaneously to the server ...

Comment: Sure that'd be nice. But often we work with existing communication protocols :)

Comment: And you cannot change it. How do you identify clients now? By Ip/Port , Socket instance, ... ?

Comment: _"TCP connection handler has to detect duplicate connections"_ does it, though? If clients have a "dumb" try-and-reconnect policy, why not just time out "silent" connections?

Comment: @Fildor my app is new so I do not yet. But it's a pre-existing, deliberately very basic protocol. I thought I could just compare `Socket` instances but that doesn't appear a built-in method so I wonder why, and how to implement it since TCP is not the easiest protocol!

Comment: _"why not just time out "silent" connections"_ - a fair point, I could squish connections _I_ think are stale and trust if they're not the clients will reconnect. Not a bad design.

Comment: At least it is fairly simple to implement. :D So, you could just give it a try and see if it works out for you.

Comment: @Fildor I may though I am interested to know if there's a good answer. Your suggestion would make a reasonable answer since it does address the key problem I think.

Answer (score 1):

Identifying a specific client is not always trivial without a protocol that already gives you a connection or client identifier.

Reiterating the approach I gave in comments (so they are not lost):

You say, your protocol is 3rd party, fix and does not provide any kind of identifier.
That means, you would have to resort to markers like IP, IP/Port, which is not the safest thing to do (without knowing more specifics).

Considering clients have a try-fail-reconnect policy, you could keep track of traffic on each connection. If connection X has not seen traffic for N amount of time, you close it.

What does that mean?

- If the client went offline, you clean up the dangling connection. Yay!
- If the client was just silent for too long, it will fail to send and reconnect - happy.
- If the client wrongfully gave up the connection and reconnected, you clean up the now dangling connection and still receive its messages - also happy.

The only **downside** I can see from the start is if you *have to* positively identify a client, you still have to figure out a way to do so.